# By setting text to UIButton resets button font to default

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

In my code, I have created a custom button (i.e subclass of UIButton), But I am unable to set the font to the button. Have observed that, If I am using `self.titleLabel?.text = title` it works fine but whenever I am using method `self.setTitle(title, for: .normal)` font get reset to system font. I need that font for all the states of the button so I have to use the function `setTitle`. My custom button code is as follows

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        styleButton()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        styleButton()
    }

    func styleButton(title: String = "button", font: UIFont = .customFont16) {
        self.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        titleLabel?.font = font
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `NSAttributedString` to specify the font of the title?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624012-setattributedtitle

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable for setting font in a custom class. Then set the font from the viewController.

```
var titleFont: UIFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote) {
    didSet {
        titleLabel?.font = titleFont
    }
}
```

Add the above code into your custom class and access it in the viewController like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var roundButton: RoundedButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    roundButton.titleFont = .caption1
}
```